# How can I play an a HTTP live video stream on my HTTPS website?

Tags: html, http, video, https, m3u8

I am trying to play a live video HTTP video stream on my HTTPS website. The HTTP video source is .m3u8. It is a device connected to my home network. I am trying to access it from anywhere over https.

I tried using  element, but it will not play.

Thanks

Comment: Is using PHP an option? If yes, you could use a PHP script (running on your HTTPS) to read and return the HTTP file. The video will still think the `.src` is from HTTPS since it using the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Keep in mind iframe is only compatible with HTML 4.01 to HTML 5, the latest one.

Try:

```
<iframe src="url_here" style="border:5px solid #000;height:350px;width:800px;" title="Iframe livestream"></iframe>
```

? ^^
Or, if you don't want a border:

```
<iframe src="url_here" style="border:none;height:350px;width:800px;" title="Iframe livestream"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this element(video tag), this element is a new element in HTML5:

```
<video src="Your address" type="video/WebM" controls="" poster="The cover" controlslist="download ablefullscreen" notautoplay="" preload="">Your bowser is not support the video tag</video>
```